# Trying to get a form button to change a value in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently trying to get a form button to change a MySQL database table field value? Any ideas where I am going wrong with this code?...

HTML button:

```
<form><form action="admin.php" method="POST">
<strong>ACTIVE MODE -</strong> Main BaseCentre website is online and active. <input type="submit" value="Maintenance Mode" class="btn btn-default" name="updateclose_site">|
</form>
```

PHP script:

```
if (isset($_POST['updateclose_site'])){
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE adminpage SET close_site='1' WHERE setting='main'");

$sql_doublecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminpage WHERE setting='main' AND close_site='1'");
$doublecheck = mysql_num_rows($sql_doublecheck);

if($doublecheck == 0){
echo "<strong><font color=red>> Close site is off</font></strong>";
} elseif ($doublecheck > 0) {
echo "<strong><font color=green>> Close site is working</strong></font><br />";

}
}
```

My database looks like this:

"headers"   setting  |  close_site (enum, 0, 1, 2, 3)
"rows"      main     |     0  (default)

Nothing happens when I click the button? Will appreciate any help!

Comment: any errors ? details?

Comment: No errors, just goes to the top of the page and doesn't echo anything?

Comment: Could you please just add an `else` statement and check is your condition true or not?

Comment: } elseif ($doublecheck > 0) {
 echo "<strong><font color=green>> Close site is working</strong></font><br />";
 
}
else 
header('Redirect: welcome.php');
}

Comment: Is that what you want me to try?

Comment: I just want to be sure that your whether your form has been submitted or not, you can also add `var_dump($_POST)` to check it

Comment: No, else for `if (isset($_POST['updateclose_site'])){}else{echo 'hi';}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change html to

```
<form action="admin.php" method="POST">
<strong>ACTIVE MODE -</strong> Main BaseCentre website is online and active. <input type="submit" value="Maintenance Mode" class="btn btn-default" name="updateclose_site">|
</form>
```

You have an extra `<form>`

Comment: Doesn't change, still does nothing? Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing. Don't use mysql_ rather use mysqli_ (or PDO) extension
[mysql_ is deprecated from php 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)